# Suspend state in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, shutdown, suspend

Setting in my computer is such that the system suspends when I close the lid.When I open the lid later on, the system boots up as though it was starting for the first time,and it was previously shut down. Once I log in to my account and start using ubuntu 14.04 , there is a message stating that system problem was encountered and suggests me to send an error report. I have recently, erased and re-installed ubuntu 14.04 and my software is up to date. This thing(system program problem), occurs each time I close my lid. And all my previous work is lost.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

go to system setting => power managment 
choose the action of closing the lid 

**or**

```
$ gksu 'gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf'
```

**then add this line**

```
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
```

**then restart systemd-logind**

```
$ sudo restart systemd-logind
```

**or** 
search for application named : configuration editor
go to 'i think it is' gnome-power-managment 'or something related to power  managment'
after that go to buttons edit lid_ac value to nothing